# Remove compiler definitions

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

when compiling shared library which links boost and python libraries I receive error:

> /usr/bin/ld: libboost_python.a(from_python.o): relocation R_X86_64_32
>   against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object;
>   recompile with -fPIC libboost_python.a: could not read symbols: Bad
>   value

I've used verbose mode to look at compiler definitions:

> /usr/bin/c++  -fPIC -g   -shared -Wl,-soname,libCore.so -o
>   .../libCore.so Core.cpp.o -lpython2.7 -Wl,-Bstatic -lboost_python
>   -Wl,-Bdynamic

That's it! I have to remove `-Wl, -Bstatic` from definitions but how to do that? I'm using cmake build system and here is a part of code which generates that shared library:

```
set(Core_SRC
    Core.cpp
)
add_definitions(-g -fPIC)
add_library(Core SHARED ${Core_SRC})

target_link_libraries(Core
    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to build a shared library with libboost_python which appears to have been built in such a way that it can't be linked into a shared library.

There's 3 ways round that.

1. Don't make your library shared
2. Build a shared version of the boost_python library
3. eave the references to boost_python unresolved

Comment: 1. Boost python module can't be non shared library? 2. I can't build it cause I have limitation for this 3. Sorry, can't understand

Comment: This: "recompile with -fPIC libboost_python.a" is telling you what you need to do. If you can't rebuild libbost_python.a, then your library can't be shared.

Presumably your build system is set up to force in that -Wl,-BStatic for some reason. If not, you should have a word with the maintainers of your build system to see if they can explain why